# AudioKit real-time recording and playback

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm trying to add a feature to my app where I can record audio from the phone's built-in microphone and then playback that audio through the phone's speakers at the same time.

Firstly, I want to know if this is possible through AudioKit?

Secondly, if it's possible, which playground/examples projects in AudioKit can I look through for reference on how to do this?

I know it's possible to record the audio to a file and then play that back and I saw it in the Recorder example project, but what I wanted was a real-time playback.

Would appreciate any guidance or help you can give me for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any app that uses the device microphone, you need to add the [NSMicrophoneUsageDescription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589998/the-apps-info-plist-must-contain-an-nsmicrophoneusagedescription-key-with-a-str) key to Info.plist. Once that's taken care of you just route the microphone through the effects, and set the output to the end of the chain.

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var microphone = AKMicrophone()
    var reverb = AKReverb()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        microphone >>> reverb
        AudioKit.output = reverb
        AKSettings.ioBufferDuration = 0.002 // Optional, set this to decrease latency
        AudioKit.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this error
: Binary operator '>>>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AKMicrophone?' and 'AKReverb?