# iOS 12 - "The app's Info.plist must contain an NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key"

Tags: ios, ios12

Today I updated to the beta of iOS 12 to give my company's app a test to see if any features requires some updates.  The only problem I've come across so far was that the app crashes when invoking the camera within it to take a picture. When doing so I received the following error:

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

I've checked out the apple site for some changes in the permissions around this but haven't found anything relevant.  The app currently works on iOS 11 without this.  Has anyone ready anything relevant to behavioral changes in this or could it be an iOS 12 beta bug?  I'm not sure why it now thinks the app needs access to the mic all of a sudden when simply taking a picture.

Thanks for your help!

Edit: I am aware there are other questions asking about this error text.  However I am not asking about the error itself, but rather whether or not this is an iOS 12 beta bug or if there is some change in security that I have overlooked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The app's Info.plist must contain an NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589998/the-apps-info-plist-must-contain-an-nsmicrophoneusagedescription-key-with-a-str)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It bug was fixed in iOS 12 beta 2:

> **UIKit** 
>   *Resolved Issues*
>   • Presenting a UIImagePickerController might cause the app to be terminated with a privacy violation if the app does not
>   include the NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key in its Info.plist.
>   (40490417)

https://download.developer.apple.com/Documentation/Beta_Release_Notes_19_June_2018_v2/iOS_12_beta_2_Release_Notes.pdf

Comment: above link is not found and content.

Comment: developer.apple.com requires authorization to view the document.
You can view release notes of iOS 12 beta in https://developer.apple.com/download/